# Controller is not defined in View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular error: Error: Argument 'StoreController as store' is not a function, got undefined

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- runs the module when the document loads -->
<html ng-app='store'>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- expressions -->
            <!-- directive    controller name    alias -->
        <div ng-controller='StoreController as store'>
            <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
            <h2>${{store.product.price}}</h2>
            <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <script type = 'text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js'></script>
        <script type ='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>

app.js

// wrap the function inside a closure.
(function(){
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    // will be executed when the store controller is called.
    this.product = gem;
});

var gem = {
    name: 'Dodecahedron',
    price: 2.95,
    description: '. . .'
};

})();
```

I am brand new to angular and keep getting the error that I posted above in my chrome console whenever I load my app.  I think everything is correct. I am not sure why the function StoreController is not defined, am I not passing the controller properly to my index.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of your code, you're running Angular 1.0.1:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' 
src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js'></script>
```

...whereas the `Controller as propertyName` syntax option wasn't added until 1.1.5. If you'd like to use that syntax, load a newer version of AngularJS. Actually, load a newer version even if you don't need that syntax ;)

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#angularjs